# How to delete from table but to prevent it from becoming empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with two columns: id (unique key) and data.

I need to delete a row from that table with id equal to some value. Obvious query:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = value
```

However, I need to prevent the table from becoming empty (i.e. without rows). In other words, I need to delete the row with id = value only if the table won't become empty after such a deletion.

I need to do it atomically in a single query, I also need to know by the result of this query whether something has been actually deleted or not.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a trigger to ensure the table doesn't become empty.

Comment: @jarlh: and if the trigger is not a solution due to some reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this one works:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ... AND (SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) Temp) > 1;
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Anyway, might be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple join for this:

```
DELETE tbl.* 
FROM tbl 
JOIN tbl tbl1 ON tbl.id <> tbl1.id WHERE tbl.id = 1;
```

In this case record deleted only exists one more record with different `id`

Try [SQL in sandbox](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=c29822c89b11cb642732541995ac3fc1&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, one can use a stored routine.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_keep_one(pID INT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE cnt INT;
   START TRANSACTION;
   DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id = pID;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM t1;
   IF cnt = 0 THEN
       ROLLBACK;
   ELSE
       COMMIT;
   end if;
END;


CALL delete_keep_one(200);
```

So the `COMMIT` will happen only when `COUNT(*)` returns greater than 0.

If you need the `CALL` within another transaction, you take out the `COMMIT` and or add a parameter which can optionally commit.